# Opencv 3.0.0 OpenCVEngineInterface

Tags: android, c++, opencv

I'm trying to install opencv 3.0.0 in Android studio IDE.
But every time I face this problem with the import of "org.opencv.engine.OpenCVEngineInterface", the IDE gives me 4 errors like:

> Error:(7, 25) error: package org.opencv.engine does not exist
>   Error:(47, 15) error: cannot find symbol class OpenCVEngineInterface
>   Error:(161, 51) error: package OpenCVEngineInterface does not exist
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':libs:opencv:compileReleaseJava'.

I go in the folder opencv/engine and there is a file called `OpenCVEngineInterface.aidl`.
All of this errors are joined by the same thing - org.opencv.engine.
I searched around, but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 12):

It is late but I found new solution for this problem and It should work without any problem. There is a solution

In build.gradle file (module :opencv) end of the android block

```
buildFeatures {
    aidl = true
    buildConfig = true
}
```

write this block and Sync. Thats all.

Answer (score 5):

It is because you haven't added package org.opencv.engine to the correct path.

In OpenCV SDK, org.opencv.engine is aidl. You need to add org.opencv.engine.OpenCVEngineInterface.aidl to the aidl directory.

You can solve this problem as following:

1、make a new directory in "main".

2、copy package org.opencv.engine to this directory like this:

[image]

After that,try again.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to right-click on the module/app like in the snapshot below. An create a dummy .aidl file. NEXT: move your .aidl file into the newly created .aidl folder

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution after adding OpenCV as module to your project you have to add 'Android' facet (Open Module Settings -> Facets) to OpenCV module and specify the paths as in normal project.

Comment: please elaborate for latest android studio, as menus are changed